# cannot change git branch in Symfony project

Tags: eclipse, git, symfony

I am working in a Symfony project with eclipse and i had to create a new branch to do some tests, but every time i want to switch branch i always get a message for the `app/cache` directory  telling me that : `the files shown below has uncommited changes and will be lost in the checkout` and it gives me some options: `commit, stash, reset, cancel`.

How can i avoid this message so i can switch directly to the branch. i tried ignore files but when i come back to the master branch and i want to change again to the new branch i get the message.

I also wanna know if there's a method to cancel ignored files, because i ignored a file by error and want to cancel the operation so i cant add it to the index again

Comment: Capitalising the first-person pronoun ("I", not "i") goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `app/cache` to your `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following command :

> git stash

With this command, you can save your modifications on the current branch.

Then, you can use the following command to switch the branch :

> git checkout BRANCHNAME

After your tests, you have to use the **git checkout** command to return on your branch.

To retrieve your modified files, type the following command :

> git stash apply

After that, you will retrieve all the precedent modified files.

Good luck :)

Comment: ok, thanks.and what about if i ignore a file by error, how can i cancel the ignore operation ?

Comment: You have to use **git stash pop**. :)